# Geolocation based augmented reality

Tags: android, geolocation, augmented-reality

My task is to develop application for Android that should be used by tourist. Basic use case: I am going through old part of some town and then i start my app, point with camera to some place and some old building that is already gone will be present in its place as it was before.

My first direction that i was exploring was location based recognizing, I tried some frameworks like Wikitude, MetaIO and DroidAR. None of these was 100% fulfilling my need, because (in my opinion), noone was using (for its robustness) the newest tools that should make easier this task, like new Google Play Services Location API. I dont know if I could do better but I would prefer not to write my own solution.

I am now thinking about exploring marker based recognition but it would require additional work to place some markers to desired places and I dont believe that user would be in right angle and distance to that marker. I have seen some video that used some sort of edge detection but none of frameworks I used had this feature.

Do you know about some direction, technology or idea that I could explore and may lead to successful solution?

Answer (score 14):

Augmented Reality will transfer real coordinates system to camera coordinates system. In AR Location-based, the real coordinate is Geographic coordinate system. We will convert the GPS coordinate (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude) to Navigation coordinate (East, North, Up), then transfer Navigation coordinate to Camera coordinate and display it on camera view.

I just create demo for you, not using any SDK

https://github.com/dat-ng/ar-location-based-android

Answer (score 4):

I personally recommend you to use "Wikitude". Because I have created AR app for android using Wikitude SDk.

Also here I'm providing you app link which has been developed by Wikitude itself.

See below link :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wikitude&hl=en

This app will give you brief idea about exploring place details using Wikitude Sdk. These sdk have free as well as paid library. It is well documented & very easy to implement. Also they have given very good sample practices for beginners.

Refer this link :

http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-augmented-reality-sdk-mobile/wikitude-sdk-android/

I hope this will take you on track.

Comment: I agree to go for a cross-platform SDK like Wikitude. You can also use augmented reality on iOS and Android devices that do not have native support for ARKit or ARCore. If your goal is to provide your AR experience to as many people as possible, this is the way to go.

You can find some showcases and code examples for augmented reality apps with Qt and Wikitude here: https://v-play.net/cross-platform-development/qt-ar-why-and-how-to-add-augmented-reality-to-your-mobile-app

Answer (score 1):

you already had some great ideas about your app. I guess these links will make you to learn more.

See links below: 
http://net.educause.edu/ir/library/pdf/ERB1101.pdf
http://www.adristorical-lands.eu/index.php/sq/augmented-reality-app

Hope this will help you to go further in your project. Thank you.